# Need help validating schema

Tags: json, schema

I am currently capturing a bunch of events locally on my disk. I have defined schema for these events. I now want to validate the results saved on my disk with the JSON schema I have written. How do I do this?

Comment: any helpful links?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a schema validation library in the language of your choice. IE https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify enough to provide a specific code example, so here is a pseudo code that may help you to find the solution using a [JSON validation library](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html) of your choice:

```
foreach (event on disk)
    if (ValidationLibraryOfMyChoice.Validate(event.ToJson(), schema)
        // handle valid events
    else
        // handle invalid events
```